# How to use custom password character in c# textbox in web forms?

Tags: passwords

I found that PasswordChar works for windows form Textbox control in this purpose, but how can I do that in case of web form?
Please help.thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the character displaying in a `<input type="password">`.

You can create a regular textbox and capturing the change event you can grab the text in it into a javascript variable and replace it with your own character.

Comment: Can you give me a sample small code for which I can mark it as answer?